# JavaScript RegEx format string containing American Express card number

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to format a string containing an American Express credit card number using a regular expression. Here's what I'm using for Visa, MasterCard and Discover number formatting, but it obviously doesn't work for American Express:

```
var formatVisaMasterCardDiscover = function (
    number) {
    return number.split(/(?=(?:\d{4})+($))/).filter(function (
        n) {
        return (n != "");
    }).join("-");
};
```

So, I'm curious what the regular expression for an Amex number would be. The format should `{4}-{6}-{5}`. I'd appreciate any help because I couldn't find anything while searching except about how to validate it which is not what I want. I want to format it.

Comment: Without dashes, it's `^3[47][0-9]{13}$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
var ccNum = '341256789012345';

var ccFmt = ccNum.replace(/\b(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d{5})\b/, '$1-$2-$3');
//=> 3412-567890-12345
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yF1iD1/1)

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much. I updated the other function in my post to work the same way rather than the string splitting weirdness it was doing.

Comment: this only works if you test a full 15 character card number.  I wanted to be able to format as you type.  I made this bit of code to suit my needs http://quercusv.github.io/smartForm/